# Cloud computing solutions for processing big datasets/ML development?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, aws, cloud-computing

I apologize in advance if my question is vague - I will edit it/follow up if it requires more context. I would also like to add that my experience is with small-ish datasets that can be run on lower-performance computers, so this problem is new to me.

I'm currently working with an enormous (at least for me) amount of data, with the combined size of the files totaling to ~192 Gb. Each file contains upwards of 3 million rows, with varying numbers of columns. As of the moment, this data is "raw", as in it has yet to be labeled and processed. I'm in possession of SAS files that process/label each dataset separately - after such a step, I am to merge all of the processed datasets together and begin developing a machine-learning model with R.

My problem is that my computer (16 Gb ram, 64-bit system) simply cannot handle this amount of data in standalone SAS or R. I've done some research and it looks like cloud computing on AWS or MS Azure can be a solution for computation on big datasets like this, but then again, this is completely unknown territory to me.

My questions are: would I be able to process and analyze my data on cloud computing software, i.e. run SAS and R programs on the data all in a platform offered by AWS/Azure/etc.? Are there any resources that could point me in the right direction to finding a solution? I am open to any suggestions at all.

Thank you very much - I appreciate any insights from you all!